# Ansible: "expect" command error saying "we were unable to convert to dict"

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Im trying to test "expect" command using ansible, however error occurred saying "we were unable to convert to dict:"

Here's the details below.

**Ansible Server info**

- ansible version - ansible 2.9.27
- python version - 2.7.12
- Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

**Ansible Playbook**

```yaml
- name: Test Expect command
  expect:
   command: openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
   responses:
    - 'Country Name': PH
    - 'State or Province Name': MM
    - 'Locality Name': Manila
    - 'Organization Name': Meta
    - 'Organizational Unit Name': Test
    - 'Common Name': Test
    - 'Email Address': rflcanelas@gmail.com
  timeout: 300
```

**Target Host info:**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-113 ~]$ hostnamectl
  Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
       CPE OS Name: cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.93-87.444.amzn2.x86_64**
```

**Ansible Command**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-15:~/ansible/dev/test/roles/proftp/tasks$ ansible-playbook -i /home/ubuntu/ec2.py /home/ubuntu/ansible/dev/test/playbook.yml
TASK [proftp : Test Expect command] **************************************************************************************************************
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument responses is of type <type 'list'> and we were unable to convert to dict: <type 'list'> cannot be converted to a dict"}
```

**Solution for now..Manually Generate SSL Cert and copy to destination path**

`````
- name: Copy SSL Certificate
  copy:
     src: proftpd.pem
     dest: /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem

- name: Set  pem permission
  file:
     path: /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
     mode: 0440
````
`````

Comment: Compare your configuration to the docs. A list should only be used **under a question** that might be repeated multiple times. At the top-level you're supposed to provide a dict, with questions as keys and strings (or lists) as actions.

Comment: It's the `-`s that make your items be list entries instead of key/value pairs in a dict. If what you meant to enter was key/value pairs instead of list items, leave the dashes out.

Comment: Problem solved after i remove dashes(-).However another error showed up says "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null.

Comment: Have you considered feeding these values as environment variables instead of using expect at all?

Comment: You can provide an `openssl.cnf` file that specifies which variable name to use for each string (or specifies a hardcoded string for things you don't need to parameterize).

Comment: Yes as long as it works.For now i just manually generate a SSL Certificate and copy to destination path.

`````
- name: Copy SSL Certificate
  copy:
     src: proftpd.pem
     dest: /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem

- name: Set  pem permission
  file:
     path: /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
     mode: 0440````